# How to iterate over jcr nodes in specific order?

Tags: aem, jcr

I was working around with the iterator to list and traverse over child nodes and I'm getting this anomalous behavior where the iterator lists the nodes in different order each time. I need to iterate over nodes as it's present in the crx/de. Is there a way it could be done, to control the order of listing!

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("path", getResource().getPath());
map.put("1_property", "sling:resourceType");
map.put("1_property.operation", "equals");
map.put("1_property.value", "/path/to/some/node");

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = 
               getResourceResolver().adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),
               getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class));
SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

In the iterator below what I'm getting in `Resource next` is the resource nodes in some random order.

```
Iterator<Resource> resources = result.getResources();
while (resources.hasNext()) {
    Resource next = resources.next();
    //The operations
}
```

It should be iterated as it's present in the crx, instead it's taking the order exclusiveofferboxes__3, exclusiveofferboxes__1, exclusiveofferboxes__2.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic The question is updated. Could you take a look.

Comment: Is your aim to get all nodes of a specific type from one parent node?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using Oak.

I remembered reading something about the ordering of nodes in OAK:

> With Apache Oak this has changed. With Oak nodes are not ordered unless its parent has node type which supports ordering.
>
> To illiustrate the difference between `sling:folder` (no ordering required) and `sling:orderedFolder` (ordering required), I did a small test. I wrote a small benchmark to create 5000 nodes, then add more nodes, do random reads and delete them afterwards. For every operation a single node is created or deleted followed by a `save()`.

Here's the link: https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/1000-nodes-per-folder-and-oak-orderable-nodes/

So, you need to have a parent node with a primary type `sling:OrderedFolder`, which is basically the ordering of the nodes.

Please use the Sling API for iteration. That's the way you should build things in AEM.

Edit: skip the QueryBuilder and try `Resource#listChildren` or `Resource#getChildren`.

Comment: Is it just that property to parent node, whatever primary or mixin type it has got? Or is it the primary type! Is there any workaround without changing the entire crx node structure. I came across something called jcr:hasOrderableChildNodes, but not sure how to work on that.

Comment: I think, based on what Jörg Hoh has written, you have to set the `jcr:primaryType` to `sling:OrderedFolder`. I don't know about this mixin type. I added a comment to my answer. There might be a possibility, that things get easier when using the Sling API directly.

Comment: But that might require a change in the entire structure of nodes using sling:OrderedFolder. Lemme try with sling API.